# Vertical scroll on 100% height div

Tags: html, css, overflow, vertical-scroll

I try to create a horizontal scrollbar in a 100% height div. In jsfiddle, the scrollbar on the right should be only visible in content-table but current the scrollbar scrolls hole page on y-axis and not only in content-table y-axis.

overflow:auto works only on x axis, why not on y?

```
.content-table {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mnlfischer/4g979nym/1/

Comment: try  overflow-y: scroll;  after overflow auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That´s because you need a heigth for .content-table try including this CSS   height: calc(100% - 100px);

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.column-lead {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.column-lead-item {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

.row-lead {
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row-lead-item {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content-table {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content-table-row {
  width: 100%;
}

.content-table-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row-lead">
    <div class="row-lead-item">Row Lead Item</div>
    <div class="row-lead-item">Row Lead Item</div>
    <div class="row-lead-item">Row Lead Item</div>
    <div class="row-lead-item">Row Lead Item</div>
    <div class="row-lead-item">Row Lead Item</div>
    <div class="row-lead-item">Row Lead Item</div>
    <div class="row-lead-item">Row Lead Item</div>
    <div class="row-lead-item">Row Lead Item</div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="content-table">
    <div class="column-lead">
    <div class="column-lead-item">Column Lead Item</div>
    <div class="column-lead-item">Column Lead Item</div>
    <div class="column-lead-item">Column Lead Item</div>
    <div class="column-lead-item">Column Lead Item</div>
    <div class="column-lead-item">Column Lead Item</div>
    <div class="column-lead-item">Column Lead Item</div>
    <div class="column-lead-item">Column Lead Item</div>
  </div><div class="content-table-row">
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-table-row">
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-table-row">
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-table-row">
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-table-row">
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-table-row">
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
      <div class="content-table-item">Content Cell</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```